# boost::bind with templated functors

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, functor, boost-bind

Just trying to get this simple test working for accessing the function operator. I have dug around the boost::bind (esp for the [overloaded section](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/bind/bind.html#err_overloaded)  ) but have not found a way to get this to work.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/bind.hpp>

template <typename FooType>
struct Foo {
    const FooType tmp_value;

    Foo(const FooType& tmp_) :
    tmp_value(tmp_)
  {
  }

    template<typename Object>
  void operator()(Object& operand)
  {
    std::cout << operand << std::endl;
    operand += tmp_value;
  }
};

int main() {


    double t = 4.0;
    Foo<double> e(1.0);
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
    e(t);   // Works
    std::cout << t << std::endl; 

    double d = 5.0;
    Foo<double> p(1.0);
    auto f1 = boost::bind(&Foo::operator(), p, _1); // Blows up at compile

    std::cout << d << std::endl;
    f1(d); 
    std::cout << d << std::endl;

}
```

Compiler output:

```
g++ -Wall --std=c++0x -I.  bind.cc -o binder
bind.cc:33:25: error: expected a class or namespace
    auto f1 = boost::bind(&Foo::operator(), p, _1); // Blows up at compile
                           ^
```

I know I am just missing something simple, any help would be awesome.

Comment: You can't take the address of a template (and you are using `Foo` without specifying a template argument). In any event, you have a functor, just bind the functor directly.

Comment: Do you need the template operator method? If you where to use the Foo typename such as `void operator()(const FooType& operand)` then `boost::bind<&Foo<double>::operator(), p, _1);` would work and also should help ensure you don't attempt to perform compound assignments on incompatible types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're attempting to take the address of a member function template without specifying the type arguments, which is not possible. Your code works if you add the type arguments for both `Foo` and `operator()`.

```
auto f1 = boost::bind(&Foo<double>::operator()<double>, p, _1);
//                        ^^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^^
```

But, as T.C. says in the comments, you already have a functor which can be bound directly as

```
auto f1 = boost::bind<void>(p, _1); // void is the return type of operator()
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb9f0f6e0d73be4f)

Answer (score 2):

As noted in a comment, you can just bind `p` because it is already a functor. And yes, it will act polymorphically, being the template that it is.

However, depending on compiler/boost versions you might not get `decltype()` goodness by default and you would have to add

```
typedef void result_type;
```

to the `Foo` functor class: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af1d511f8abe321a)**

Alternatively, you could `#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE` before including any boost headers.